# Windows 8 store package fails on WACK when login to developer account

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, package, windows-store-apps, app-certification-kit

I'm trying to put a simple app on windows store. I made a fail attempt once, I submitted an app which failed to pass WACK, eventually it failed on submission too. Even then, when I try to package an app with my developer account logged in, I get a performance launch error.

Even on a blank app. also right after I create package logged in, my app's package name and provider fields on appmanifest are changes too. app's package name changes to the first app I submitted, and the provider changes to I guess my developer account's key.

I deleted my failed submission on dashboard, deleted all the names I reserved, including the failed one. But even when I reserve a new name and package my app with that name, my package name still changes to the very first one and fails on wack.

BUT, when I create package of my app WITHOUT logging in, I mean without associate with windows store, I can package my app with the name I want and pass the WACK. I hope anyone can help me with this.

Edit: C# application.

Comment: is this a HTML5/JavaScript app?  And it fails for say a simple File>New template with no code?  I have seen similar issues with WACK failures on one machine but not another, but not correlated them with being logged in.  If you run the app do you see similar slowness to launch? and if so, how does it behave when you run in the simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this happen too, it seems like WACK got confused and kept trying to verify the wrong version. The following steps resolved it for me:

1. Uninstall the app from your development PC (as in, go to start page,
   right click on the app and select uninstall).
2. Reboot the dev PC.
3. Select "Local Machine" and "Release".
4. Start debugging wait for it to
   have started up completely and then stop debugging.

Pretty sure that only one or two of those steps are actually needed, but not sure which ones.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure I understand your issue, but let me try...

First, what is the failure that you got when you submitted to the Store and when you ran the WACK?  You mentioned a "performance launch error".  If you are failing the performance test, check out [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2012/11/14/common-windows-store-certification-errors-3-8-app-must-meet-the-basic-performance-criteria-on-a-low-power-computer.aspx) for tips to help.  Some examples:

- Package content locally (or cache it) when possible, so you don’t have to pull resources from a network during launch.
- Load and do only what you need on launch.  You can load other data and do other work asynchronously in the background or when you actually need it.
- Use a "dirty bit" when saving data on suspend, so you only save data that has changed.  (Rather than re-serializing your app’s state if that data hasn’t changed, create a Boolean flag variable (or “dirty bit”) which signals that your data has been modified, and only re-serialize when the data has changed.)
- Use bytecode caching if you are developing in JavaScript, so each JS file has bytecode created once and not every time the app launches.  To enable this, make sure all JavaScript files are UTF8 encoded with a byte-order mark (BOM) and are statically referenced in the root of your HTML start page.

If this is not the error that the WACK and your Store certification is failing with, please see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2012/11/12/common-certification-errors-when-submitting-to-the-windows-store.aspx) and the related blog posts that it links to, to see if your failure is covered there.

Secondly, your issue with associating your code with your reserved name in the Windows Store:

> also right after I create package logged in, my app's package name and
>   provider fields on appmanifest are changes too.

This behavior is expected.  When you associate your app package with the Windows Store, it will change the "Package name" and the publisher in your appxmanifest.  But that's okay!  The "Package name" is just what the Windows Store uses as an internal identifier for your app package, and the "Package display name" (right below it in the appxmanifest) is what your end users will see.  Set the "Package display name" to what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There is no issue with performance. I'm sure it's something different than performance. I tracked down the WACK's logs and I found out when I create a package associate with Store, it changes my package name to the same name as the first FAILED submission of mine. Also for some reason, it can't read the App Launch data in those logs. I tacked it and where the WACK checks the launch time of my app, when I associate it, it shows zero for everything, it can't read from xperf.txt file. But when I locally package it and run WACK, it can read launch time data from xperf.txt

Comment: I found 2 posts on the MSDN forums that might help.  Check out http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/04c8ca91-59ad-4292-b9a4-9a84b1b135bd and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/3680f2e2-310b-425c-8371-4e18653fb611.  Does this describe your problem accurately?

Comment: If so, some possible fixes are: delete everything under \Users\[YOUR_USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\AppCertKit and re-run the WACK tool again, or increase your RAM.

Comment: I already cleared AppCertKit and rerun the tool. No help there. As for the msdn posts, I already saw those and no help from those either. Not quite like my problem. Here is the only posts that I found exacly like mines; http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsstore/thread/a5a2dd0a-b941-4c01-bc90-86855f87b760

Comment: Saying this again, but I'm pretty SURE thats not a real performance problem. Because when I create my package locally and run WACK, I can pass it easily. Whenever I try to create a package in Visual Studio with logging in to my account, it fails on WACK. This is the only problem. I'm explaining it again. First I create a New Project in Visual Studio. Then I (without do anything) create a package from    Store->Create app packages.. Now after this, if I say NO to the question that popped up about the store, my wack won't give performance launch error. But if I select YES and then log in

Comment: and create the package, WACK will give an error like this FAILED -Performance Launch - ...launch was not detected... after this, every time when I create a package for that app, the wack will give the same error, locally or logged in.